# What should I add to the .py file that has been generated from pyuic5 so that when I execute the .py, the gui will appear?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

when I converted the .ui file from Qt to .py, I try to run it but it does not show the gui I created with Qt. I have tried adding

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    screen = Ui_Form()
    screen.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

at the end of my code but it returns an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Path***.py", line 12,
>   in 
>       class Ui_Form(object):   File "C:\Path****.py", line 355, in Ui_Form
>       screen = Ui_Form() NameError: name 'Ui_Form' is not defined

This is my code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class Ui_Form(object):
  def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName("Form")
    Form.resize(490, 264)
*insert some more generated codes here*

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
    self.Load_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Load"))
    self.Load_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Load"))
*insert some more generated codes here*
```

Comment: Typically the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) is a good place to look, but unfortunately it is offline at the moment. When it comes back, I'd encourage you to take a look as there are a few different ways you can handle using the ui/py file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add more code to the file generated by the pyuic tool.  Instead, subclass the Ui class that is in the file.  By doing this you can change the gui and use the pyuic tool again without losing all of the code you wrote. It would look like this:

(in another file)

```
from pyuic_generated_file import UiForm

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # code here
```

Then in your main method:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks for the info, it worked! I am pretty new in PyQt5 and I am really greatful for you answer :)